# Replication from multiple masters to one slave

Tags: replication, mariadb, master-slave-replication, mariadb-10.3, mariadb-10.5

I have 2 Raspberry PI's and each run a MariaDB 10.3 server. Each has the same databases:

- vennens
- scheduler

On the slave I've configured the `50-server.conf` file with follow contents:

```
master_pi1.replicate_do_db=scheduler_pi1

master_pi1.replicate_do_db=vennens_pi1

master_pi2.replicate_do_db=scheduler_pi2

master_pi2.replicate_do_db=vennens_pi2

master_pi1.replicate_rewrite_db=scheduler->scheduler_pi1
master_pi1.replicate_rewrite_db=vennens->vennens_pi1
master_pi2.replicate_rewrite_db=scheduler->scheduler_pi2
master_pi2.replicate_rewrite_db=vennens->vennens_pi2
```

Then I have run the `CHANGE MASTER` queries with the correct information.
When I update data on the PI's, they are not synced with the slave. I see an error when I ask for statuses.

[image: error example]

I've removed the **replicate_rewrite_db** and did the process all over again for replication but now each has Raspberry PI has an unique database name. And this setup works. There is nothing wrong with the connection.

I also see in the relay log of each connection that queries are received.

On the server I run MariaDB 10.5

What could be the issue here?

I've read:

- https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/multisource-replication-how-to-resolve-the-schema-name-conflicts
- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/setting-up-replication/

Answer (score 2):

Replication *maintains* synchronization of the data.  It does not *initialize* the Repicas.

That is, you must *first* copy the data from the Primaries to the Replica, *then* establish the "multi-source" replication.

If writes (to the Primaries) are happening *during* the setup, it gets tricky to avoid losing them.

Comment: I've done that with mysqldump on the master and changed the database name in de dump to the database name for the slave 'vennens' (master) -> 'vennens_pi1' (slave)

Then I imported these to the slave server. Then changed the configuration and restarted the mariadb service. The tables where locked on the master to get he position.